# Better way of comparing two lists with LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq, custom-lists

I have the 2 collections:

```
IEnumerable<Element> allElements
List<ElementId> someElements,
```

What is a concise way of doing the following together:

[1] Verifying that all elements in `someElements` exist in `allElements`, return quickly when condition fails.

and

[2] Obtain a list of `Element` objects that `List<ElementId> someElements` maps to.

Every `Element` object has an `ElementId`

Thank you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would do this:

```
var map = allElements.ToDictionary(x => x.Id);    
if (!someElements.All(id => map.ContainsKey(id))
{
    // Return early
}
var list = someElements.Select(x => map[x])
                       .ToList();
```

Note that the first line will throw an exception if there are any duplicates in `allElements`.

Comment: this is awesome solution, this clearly shows that while using linq people still need to understand complexity and other fundamental algorithmic stuff. but for small lists it may be an overhead.

Comment: In the case where there are duplicates, your DistinctBy method from MoreLinq would come in handy: http://code.google.com/p/morelinq/source/browse/trunk/MoreLinq/DistinctBy.cs

Answer (score 1):

1. `someElements.All(e => allElements.Contains(e));`
2. `allElements.Where(e => someElements.Contains(e.ElementId));`

Answer (score 1):

Not as efficient as the Skeet answer, but good enough for reasonable-sized collections:

```
IEnumerable<Element> allElements = new List<Element>
    { new Element { Id = 1 }, new Element { Id = 2 } };
List<int> someElements = new List<int> { 1, 2 };

var query =
    (from element in allElements
    join id in someElements on element.Id equals id
    select element)
    .ToList();

if (query.Count != someElements.Count)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not all items found.");
}

foreach (var element in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine ("Found: " + element.Id);
}
```